# Having trouble integrating D3.js (collapsible tree) into Angular application

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'm working on an angular application. I want to add in the following [d3 chart](https://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950), however when I simply plug in the Javascript into my controller, styles into my stylesheet, nothing appears. Something is suggesting to me that the Angular and D3 aren't playing nice.

I have attached my angular setup without adding in the d3 object. I would like to add it into the workHistory Controller/Directive/View. Any suggestions on what the proper way to set this up would be? Thanks!

**Index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="webApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>My Portfolio</title>

        <!--Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/d3.tree.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css"/>
        <!--Libraries -->
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
        <!--Module -->
        <script src="scripts/modules/module.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/modules/d3.module.js"></script>
        <!--Controllers -->
        <script src="scripts/controllers/mainHeroController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/workHistoryController.js"></script>
        <!--Directives-->
        <script src="scripts/directives/mainHero.directive.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/mainNavbar.directive.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/workHistory.directive.js"></script>
    </head>

     <!--Main Landing Page-->    
    <body>
        <main-navbar></main-navbar>
        <main-hero></main-hero>
        <div id="container1" ng-controller="WorkHistoryController"> 
            <h3 id="tree-title">Work History</h3>
                <work-history chart-data="$scope.values"></work-history>
            </div>
        <div id="container2">
            Container 2
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**workHistory.directive.js**

```
 (function()
    {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('webApp')
        .directive('workHistory', workHistory);

    function workHistory()
    {
        var directive = 
            {
                restrict: 'E',
                controller: 'WorkHistoryController',
                controllerAs: 'workhistory',
                scope: {},
                templateUrl: './views/workHistory.html'
            };

        return directive;

    }
    })();
```

**workHistoryController.js**

```
 (function() 
  {

'use strict'

angular
    .module('webApp')
    .controller('WorkHistoryController', WorkHistoryController);

WorkHistoryController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function WorkHistoryController($scope) 
    {            
     console.log($scope);
      $scope.values = $scope.values || {};    
      $scope.values = {
         "name": "Work History",
         "children": [
          {
           "name": "analytics",
           "children": [
            {
             "name": "cluster",
             "children": [
              {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
              {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
              {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
              {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "graph",
             "children": [
              {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
              {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
              {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
              {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
              {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "optimization",
             "children": [
              {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
             ]
            }
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "animate",
           "children": [
            {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
            {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
            {
             "name": "interpolate",
             "children": [
              {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
              {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
              {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
              {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
              {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
              {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
              {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
              {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
              {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
            {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
            {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
            {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
            {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
            {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
            {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
            {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
            {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "data",
           "children": [
            {
             "name": "converters",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
              {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
              {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
              {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
              {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
            {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
            {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
            {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
            {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
            {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "display",
           "children": [
            {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
            {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
            {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
            {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "flex",
           "children": [
            {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "physics",
           "children": [
            {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
            {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
            {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
            {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
            {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
            {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
            {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
            {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "query",
           "children": [
            {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
            {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
            {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
            {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
            {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
            {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
            {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
            {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
            {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
            {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
            {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
            {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
            {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
            {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
            {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
            {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
            {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
            {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
            {
             "name": "methods",
             "children": [
              {"name": "add", "size": 593},
              {"name": "and", "size": 330},
              {"name": "average", "size": 287},
              {"name": "count", "size": 277},
              {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
              {"name": "div", "size": 595},
              {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
              {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
              {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
              {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
              {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
              {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
              {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
              {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
              {"name": "max", "size": 283},
              {"name": "min", "size": 283},
              {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
              {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
              {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
              {"name": "not", "size": 386},
              {"name": "or", "size": 323},
              {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
              {"name": "range", "size": 772},
              {"name": "select", "size": 296},
              {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
              {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
              {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
              {"name": "update", "size": 307},
              {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
              {"name": "where", "size": 299},
              {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
              {"name": "_", "size": 264}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
            {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
            {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
            {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
            {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
            {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
            {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
            {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
            {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
            {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "scale",
           "children": [
            {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
            {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
            {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
            {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
            {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
            {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
            {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
            {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
            {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
            {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "util",
           "children": [
            {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
            {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
            {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
            {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
            {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
            {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
            {
             "name": "heap",
             "children": [
              {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
              {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
            {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
            {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
            {
             "name": "math",
             "children": [
              {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
              {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
              {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
            {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
            {
             "name": "palette",
             "children": [
              {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
              {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
              {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
              {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
            {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
            {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
            {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
            {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "vis",
           "children": [
            {
             "name": "axis",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
              {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
              {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
              {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
              {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "controls",
             "children": [
              {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
              {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
              {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
              {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
              {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
              {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
              {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
              {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
              {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
              {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
              {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "data",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
              {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
              {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
              {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
              {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
              {
               "name": "render",
               "children": [
                {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
               ]
              },
              {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
              {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
              {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "events",
             "children": [
              {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
              {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
              {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
              {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "legend",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
              {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
              {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "operator",
             "children": [
              {
               "name": "distortion",
               "children": [
                {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
               ]
              },
              {
               "name": "encoder",
               "children": [
                {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
               ]
              },
              {
               "name": "filter",
               "children": [
                {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
               ]
              },
              {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
              {
               "name": "label",
               "children": [
                {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
               ]
              },
              {
               "name": "layout",
               "children": [
                {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
               ]
              },
              {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
              {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
              {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
              {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
              {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
           ]
          }
         ]
        };
    }
})();
```

**workHistory.html**

```
  //insert d3 view here
```

**main.css**

```
 //insert d3 styles here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple to make an `angular` application and using `d3` in your application. First of all you need to learn something about the `angular` structure. As you know you need `ng-app` to using angular library, You can define it in `html` or `body` tag. If you want to share data between your directives or working with angular `services` you need angular controller. In this case `$scope` is shared between controller and directives. The last function you have to use is directive. 
So according to this passage let's normalize your code. First of all you shouldn't define a directive for `css` parameter, Just add all of them to a file and inject it inside the main page or insert them in to the `<style>` tag. 
As I mention directive just use by `JavaScript` functions. 
So let's Implement angular application:

```
var app = angular.module('App');
var ctrl = app.controller("treeCrtl", ["$scope", function ($scope) { 
}]);
```

These are two functions, The `ng-app` and the angular controller and this is the directive.

```
ctrl.directive("workHistory", function () {
         return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function link(scope, el, attr) {

                    var div = d3.select("body")
                        .append("div") // declare the tooltip div
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")
                        .style("opacity", 0);

                    var margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 },
                        width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
                        height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                    var i = 0,duration = 750,root,select2_data;
                    var diameter = 960;
                    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                        .size([height, width]);

                    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

                    var svg = d3.select(el[0]).append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                    //recursively collapse children
                    function collapse(d) {
                        if (d.children) {
                            d._children = d.children;
                            d._children.forEach(collapse);
                            d.children = null;
                        }
                    }

                    // Toggle children on click.
                    function click(d) {
                        if (d.children) {
                            d._children = d.children;
                            d.children = null;
                        }
                        else {
                            d.children = d._children;
                            d._children = null;
                        }
                        update(d);
                    }

                    function openPaths(paths) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                            if (paths[i].id !== "1") {//i.e. not root
                                paths[i].class = 'found';
                                if (paths[i]._children) { //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                                    paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                                    paths[i]._children = null;
                                }
                                update(paths[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                        root = values;
                        select2_data = extract_select2_data(values, [], 0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
                        root.x0 = height / 2;
                        root.y0 = 0;
                        root.children.forEach(collapse);
                        update(root);
                        //init search box
                        $("#search").select2({
                            data: select2_data,
                            containerCssClass: "search"
                        });


                    //attach search box listener
                    $("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
                        var paths = searchTree(root, e.object.text, []);
                        if (typeof (paths) !== "undefined") {
                            openPaths(paths);
                        } else {
                            alert(e.object.text + " not found!");
                        }
                    });

                    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

                    function update(source) {
                        // Compute the new tree layout.
                        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                        links = tree.links(nodes);

                        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                        nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

                        // Update the nodesâ€¦
                        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                            .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

                        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
                        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                            .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
                        .on("click", click);

                        nodeEnter.append("circle")
                        .attr("r", 1e-6)
                        .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

                        nodeEnter.append("text")
                            .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .attr("text-anchor", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
                            .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
                            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                        // Transition nodes to their new position.
                        var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

                        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                            .attr("r", 4.5)
                            .style("fill", function (d) {
                                if (d.class === "found") {
                                    return "#ff4136"; //red
                                }
                                else if (d._children) {
                                    return "lightsteelblue";
                                }
                                else {
                                    return "#fff";
                                }
                            })
                            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                                if (d.class === "found") {
                                    return "#ff4136"; //red
                                }
                            });

                        nodeUpdate.select("text")
                            .style("fill-opacity", 1);

                        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
                            .remove();

                        nodeExit.select("circle")
                            .attr("r", 1e-6);

                        nodeExit.select("text")
                            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                        // Update the linksâ€¦
                        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                            .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });

                        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
                        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                            .attr("class", "link")
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                                var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
                                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                            });

                        // Transition links to their new position.
                        link.transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("d", diagonal)
                            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                                if (d.target.class === "found") {
                                    return "#ff4136";
                                }
                            });

                        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                        link.exit().transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                                var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
                                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                            })
                            .remove();

                        // Stash the old positions for transition.
                        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                            d.x0 = d.x;
                            d.y0 = d.y;
                        });
                    }

                    function searchTree(obj, search, path) {
                        if (obj.name === search) { //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
                            path.push(obj);
                            return path;
                        }
                        else if (obj.children || obj._children) { //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
                            var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
                            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                                path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one
                                var found = searchTree(children[i], search, path);
                                if (found) {// we were right, this should return the bubbled-up path from the first if statement
                                    return found;
                                }
                                else {//we were wrong, remove this parent from the path and continue iterating
                                    path.pop();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {//not the right object, return false so it will continue to iterate in the loop
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    function extract_select2_data(node, leaves, index) {
                        if (node.children) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
                                index = extract_select2_data(node.children[i], leaves, index)[0];
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            leaves.push({ id: ++index, text: node.name });
                        }
                        return [index, leaves];
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

There is some points I have to mention:

1- If you have to implement different directives, Just use the same format with different names.

2- To link your code to the directive tag you have to use this type of coding:
`d3.select(el[0])`, Attention `el` is the link function parameter.

3- If you use different directory for `flare.json` replace this part:

```
root = values;
select2_data = extract_select2_data(values, [], 0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
root.children.forEach(collapse);
 update(root);
 //init search box
 $("#search").select2({
   data: select2_data,
   containerCssClass: "search"
 });
```

With this:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error,values){
        root = values;
        select2_data = extract_select2_data(values,[],0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;
        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
        //init search box
        $("#search").select2({
            data: select2_data,
            containerCssClass: "search"
        });
    });
```

Here is the whole code:

**Js part:**

```
        var app = angular.module('App');
        var ctrl = app.controller("treeCrtl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

        }]);
        ctrl.directive("workHistory", function () {
         return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function link(scope, el, attr) {

                    var div = d3.select("body")
                        .append("div") // declare the tooltip div
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")
                        .style("opacity", 0);

                    var margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 },
                        width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
                        height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                    var i = 0,duration = 750,root,select2_data;
                    var diameter = 960;
                    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                        .size([height, width]);

                    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

                    var svg = d3.select(el[0]).append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                    //recursively collapse children
                    function collapse(d) {
                        if (d.children) {
                            d._children = d.children;
                            d._children.forEach(collapse);
                            d.children = null;
                        }
                    }

                    // Toggle children on click.
                    function click(d) {
                        if (d.children) {
                            d._children = d.children;
                            d.children = null;
                        }
                        else {
                            d.children = d._children;
                            d._children = null;
                        }
                        update(d);
                    }

                    function openPaths(paths) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                            if (paths[i].id !== "1") {//i.e. not root
                                paths[i].class = 'found';
                                if (paths[i]._children) { //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                                    paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                                    paths[i]._children = null;
                                }
                                update(paths[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    root = values;
                    //values is the flare.json 
                    select2_data = extract_select2_data(values, [], 0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
                    root.x0 = height / 2;
                    root.y0 = 0;
                    root.children.forEach(collapse);
                    update(root);
                    //init search box
                   $("#search").select2({
                     data: select2_data,
                     containerCssClass: "search"
                    });

                    //attach search box listener
                    $("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
                        var paths = searchTree(root, e.object.text, []);
                        if (typeof (paths) !== "undefined") {
                            openPaths(paths);
                        } else {
                            alert(e.object.text + " not found!");
                        }
                    });

                    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

                    function update(source) {
                        // Compute the new tree layout.
                        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                        links = tree.links(nodes);

                        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                        nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

                        // Update the nodesâ€¦
                        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                            .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

                        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
                        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                            .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
                        .on("click", click);

                        nodeEnter.append("circle")
                        .attr("r", 1e-6)
                        .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

                        nodeEnter.append("text")
                            .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .attr("text-anchor", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
                            .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
                            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                        // Transition nodes to their new position.
                        var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

                        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                            .attr("r", 4.5)
                            .style("fill", function (d) {
                                if (d.class === "found") {
                                    return "#ff4136"; //red
                                }
                                else if (d._children) {
                                    return "lightsteelblue";
                                }
                                else {
                                    return "#fff";
                                }
                            })
                            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                                if (d.class === "found") {
                                    return "#ff4136"; //red
                                }
                            });

                        nodeUpdate.select("text")
                            .style("fill-opacity", 1);

                        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
                            .remove();

                        nodeExit.select("circle")
                            .attr("r", 1e-6);

                        nodeExit.select("text")
                            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                        // Update the linksâ€¦
                        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                            .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });

                        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
                        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                            .attr("class", "link")
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                                var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
                                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                            });

                        // Transition links to their new position.
                        link.transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("d", diagonal)
                            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                                if (d.target.class === "found") {
                                    return "#ff4136";
                                }
                            });

                        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                        link.exit().transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                                var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
                                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                            })
                            .remove();

                        // Stash the old positions for transition.
                        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                            d.x0 = d.x;
                            d.y0 = d.y;
                        });
                    }

                    function searchTree(obj, search, path) {
                        if (obj.name === search) { //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
                            path.push(obj);
                            return path;
                        }
                        else if (obj.children || obj._children) { //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
                            var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
                            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                                path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one
                                var found = searchTree(children[i], search, path);
                                if (found) {// we were right, this should return the bubbled-up path from the first if statement
                                    return found;
                                }
                                else {//we were wrong, remove this parent from the path and continue iterating
                                    path.pop();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {//not the right object, return false so it will continue to iterate in the loop
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    function extract_select2_data(node, leaves, index) {
                        if (node.children) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
                                index = extract_select2_data(node.children[i], leaves, index)[0];
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            leaves.push({ id: ++index, text: node.name });
                        }
                        return [index, leaves];
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

**Html part:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>flare</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .node {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .found {
            fill: #ff4136;
            stroke: #ff4136;
        }
        .node text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
        /*Just to ensure the select2 box is "glued" to the top*/
        .search {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="treeCrtl">
    <div id="search"></div>
    <work-history></work-history>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 1**

I made a live [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ggGsQ8FjApvNcdpzTOs?p=preview), I hope this help.

Comment: If you still don't figure out how to integrate your angular application, Check  update 1.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, it works, thanks! For cleaner, code, how can I migrate the data from the directive to the controller, in the example prior to the update 'treeCtrl' is an empty controller.

Comment: It's very simple to migrate the data from the directive to the controller, You just have add data to the `$scope` in controller and read data from the directive in `scope`. For example `scope.data=root;` put root data to the `scope.data` and you have access to data in controller just with this structure: `$scope.data`. The controller in Angular is looks like controller in `asp.net mvc`  model. If you have Multi directive just define a controller and use directives with shared data and functions from it.

Answer (score 2):

So it's hard to know for sure without seeing your actual D3 code, but I believe the issue is where you're loading your D3 script.

Basically, you're running your D3 script in your controller, which is too late. By the time a controller is instantiated, the DOM has already been rendered by Angular. This is true even on a directive. To manipulate the DOM (like appending a D3 visualization), you need to move your D3 script to the directive's `link` function. The `link` function in a directive is run once for each instance of the directive in order to compile the directive's view against the correct scope and create the DOM.

```
function link (scope, element, attributes) {
  // D3 code here
}

var directive = 
  {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    controller: 'WorkHistoryController',
    controllerAs: 'workhistory',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: './views/workHistory.html'
  };

return directive;
```

[Here's a good example of creating a D3 directive](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3)

[And here's a good overview of Angular directives which details the link phase](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/)